# Symfony/Doctrine Many to Many join / select not working

Tags: php, mysql, join, doctrine

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
select * from table1 left join table2 on table1.field1=table2.field1 and table1.filed2=table2.filed2
```

...but in DQL. The fields on which I am joining the tables have the same names in both tables. I am not allowed to modify the table structure or column names.

In the Symfony Entity for Table1, I have created the following association and have generated getters and setters:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Table2")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Table1_Table2",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="field1", referencedColumnName="field1"), @ORM\JoinColumn(name="field2", referencedColumnName="field2")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="field1", referencedColumnName="field1"), @ORM\JoinColumn(name="field2", referencedColumnName="field2")}
 *      )
 */
private $table1_table2;
```

After I update the db schema and try to perform a query like this:

```
$results = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Table1")->createQueryBuilder(t)->leftJoin('t.table1_table2', 'a');
```

...I just get the colums/results from table1. If I do a innerJoin instead of leftJoin, I do not get any results.

What could I be doing wrong? Is it possible to do something like this using DQL?